# Updating UI elements in a background thread before being added to a view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I am just trying to wrap my head around Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) and I cant seem to find an answer on this

So I know that in general you aren't supposed to update UIView elements from any thread other than the main thread. So this is illegal:

```
dispatch_async(workerQueue, ^{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
});
```

But are you allowed to work on view elements before they are actually added to the view? In other words, is this allowed?

```
dispatch_async(workerQueue, ^{
    UIButton *thisLevelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    thisLevelButton.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    thisLevelButton.tag = kLevelButtonTags + j;


    int levelState = [[[thisCat objectForKey:[levelNamesInCat objectAtIndex:j]] objectAtIndex:4] intValue];

    [thisLevelButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ccLSButton50lock"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    thisLevelButton.alpha = 0.5;
    [thisLevelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(unlockButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.view addSubview:thisLevelButton];
    }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. Best practice is not to **update**. Initialisation is fine.

[An example can be read in this blog post.](http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2011/02/28/cocoa-touch-tutorial-using-grand-central-dispatch-for-asynchronous-table-view-cells/) It is almost on the lines of what you are attempting.